# How to use Unix to pass all lines as parameters to a script

Tags: bash, unix, cat

I have a file called pids.txt that contains lines, such as the following:

```
123
456
789
```

Then, I wrote a Python script that does something with each line.  The Python script gets run like:

```
my_script.py 123 456 789 -a "something here" -b "something else"
```

I am stuck at the part where I want to run a Unix command, piping the outputs of pids.txt to my_script.py.  I think you have to do something with cat?

(This doesn't work)

```
cat pids.txt | ./myscript.py -a "something here" -b "something else"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$(command)` construct (equivalent of backticks: `command`):

```
./myscript.py $(cat pids.txt) -a "something here" -b "something else"
```

The construct `$(command)` runs the *command* and substitutes the standard output of the *command* where the construct is placed.

Bash also provides you with `$(< file)` construct:

```
./myscript.py $(< pids.txt) -a "something here" -b "something else"
```

This reads the `pids.txt` file and substitutes its contents for the `$(< ...)` construct. (*Thanks for this one go to glenn jackman*)

Comment: for bash, you can avoid calling out to cat with `$(< pids.txt)` that is run inside the shell.

Comment: @Jeff, note the `$(< pids.txt)` portion is NOT quoted, so each line will be passed to your python program as a separate argument. If you were to write `"$(<pids.txt)" you would get a single, newline-separated, argument.